# Как правильно работать с JSONResource Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Коллеги, прошу вашей помощи! ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

Пишу я backend REST-api составляющую для одного проекта.

У меня есть api-маршрут domain.ru/api/offices, который должен возвращать список офисов и сотрудников (employees), трудящихся в каждом офисе.

Я создал OfficeResource и OfficeCollection для получения одного и многих офисов соответственно, также приведу код EmployeeResource

**OfficeResource**

```
return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "code" => $this->code,
            "address" => $this->address,
            "employees" => new EmployeeCollection($this->employees),
            "created_at" => $this->created_at
];
```

**EmployeeResource**

```
 return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "name" => $this->name,
            "office" => $this->office
        ];
```

Для коллекций я просто создал с помощью artisan-интерфейса EmployeeCollection и OfficeCollection и ничего там не менял (ну как всегда делается) ¯\*(ツ)*/¯

**код api.php**

```
Route::get('offices', function (Request $request) {
    $office_collection = new OfficeCollection(Office::all());
    foreach ($office_collection as $office) {
        foreach ($office->employees as $employee) {
            unset($employee['id_office']);
        }
    }
    return response()->json([
        "status" => true,
        "response" => $office_collection,
    ], 200);
});
```

Так вот в чем проблема, у меня есть роут domain.ru/api/employees, который должен возвращать всех сотрудников и офис каждого сотрудника, в котором он работает
Но также у меня есть роут domain.ru/api/offices, который возвращает офисы и сотрудников, работающих в них

Просто в роуте domain.ru/api/employees я должен включать офис в Json-ответ, а в роуте domain.ru/api/offices офис будет как бы "главным" и в него будет входить сотрудник и там он включаться не должен. Единственное, что я придумал, это unset'нуть офис с помощью foreach. Как думаете, правильно ли это? Вроде тут JSONResource должен быть один (судя по туторам, которым я смотрел) но я блин никак не могу понять, как мне без костыля сделать.

**вот, что происходит в моем "костыльном" коде**. У меня как бы office остается null, но блин, это 100% неправильно

```
{
    "status": true,
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "code": "e4bK4A0UIE",
            "address": "Ленина, 10",
            "employees": [
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "name": "Elyssa Grady",
                    "office": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 8,
                    "name": "Manuel Schimmel",
                    "office": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 10,
                    "name": "Thelma Vandervort",
                    "office": null
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2021-04-11T12:50:56.000000Z"
        },
}
```

впринципе с костылем у меня всё работает правильно --> domain.ru/api/employees возвращает то, что нужно
(ниже код прикрепил), однако я думаю это наотрез неправильный подход, что я вручную что-то unset'аю

**api.php**

```
Route::get('employees', function (Request $request) {
    return response()->json([
        "status" => true,
        "response" => new EmployeeCollection(Employee::all())
    ], 200);
});
```

**возвращаемый ответ domain.ru/api/employees**

```
{
    "status": true,
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Schuyler Kilback",
            "office": {
                "id": 4,
                "code": "8ZJzJpdNe!",
                "address": "ySm7XUUIgpkWYfuHoaFG",
                "created_at": "2021-04-11T12:50:56.000000Z"
            }
        },
     ]
}
```

Comment: По сути всё нормально, у вас же нет условия когда выводитб данные офиса, а когда нет - в этом случае можно было использовать [when](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-attributes). В принципе можете не подгружать офис в модели ORM, и использовать [whenLoaded](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov не понял, как работает whenLoaded, зато понятно как работает when. Не могу их связать со своей историей, я думаю whenLoaded нужно где-то применить (чуйка), но я даже не понимаю, что он делает. 
P.S. Если тяжело общаться через форум, можно продолжить в телеграмме (был бы премного благодарен конечно ,но это я уже наглею чувствую)